# How to use items in Dictionary from within a Class?

Tags: python, class, oop, dictionary

I would like to have a character's gender use pronouns when printing such as:

"The Kings Guard" pulls "his" sword.

"his" being the important part.

I get this error: 
TypeError: pronoun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
class Player(object):
    # instantiates each character with a range of functions
    def __init__(self, name, health, lives, gender, inventory):
        self.name = name
        self.health = int(health)
        self.lives = int(lives)
        self.gender = gender
        self.inventory = []

    def pronoun(self):

        if 'male' in self.gender:
            nouns = {
                'them': 'he',
                'their': 'his'
            }
        if 'female' in self.gender:
            nouns = {
                'them': 'she',
                'their': 'her'
            }

        return nouns

player = Player("Kate", 100, 3, 'female', 'Axe')
kingsguard = Player("The Kings Guard", 150, 1, 'male', None)
a_noun = Player.pronoun()

print(kingsguard.a_noun['them'])
```

Comment: `Player.pronoun()` is wrong. Did you mean `kingsguard.pronoun()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic overcomplicates the problem. You can access the method of a class **instance** directly:

```
print(kingsguard.pronoun()['them'])  # 'he'
```

`a_noun = Player.pronoun()` will not work as desired because the class needs to know which instance `pronoun` belongs to. Otherwise, it will not be able to access `self.gender`.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am still learning the basics and trying to push myself by using classes and dictionaries/lists. Excuse my noobism! Your help is very welcome!